# ActionController::DoubleRenderError in Controls/itemsController#update Can only render or redirect

Tags: redirect, parent, render

```
  responds_to_parent do
      render :update do |page|
          page << "tb_remove"
          item_link = params[:controller].eql?("compliance_items") ? edit_compliance_compliance_item_path(master, @master_item) : edit_controls_item_path(@master_item)
          #          page.redirect_to(item_link + "?token=#{params[:token]}")
     end
 end
```

Hi in the above code I am gettign double render error(subject line is the error )... can anybody please help?

it is also vary bad to - stack over flow is not giving any option to create a new tag without reputation..!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call both `render` and `redirect_to`. That is what you have done (calling `redirect_to` inside the `render` block.

To redirect in some cases, you will need to move the `if` condition outside the `render` block. Try something like this:

```ruby
if I_need_to_redirect
  item_link = params[:controller].eql?("compliance_items") ? edit_compliance_compliance_item_path(master, @master_item) : edit_controls_item_path(@master_item)
  redirect_to item_link
else
  responds_to_parent do
    render :update do |page|
      page << "tb_remove"
    end
  end
end
```

Where `I_need_to_redirect` should be replaced with the condition for checking whether you should redirect (if false, it should render instead).